# Rails installation on Ubuntu intel 64bit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to install rails on ubuntu (Linux kumar-Dell-System-XPS-L502X 3.0.0-16-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 14 12:48:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

I am using command: 
gem install rails --version 2.3.11
Successfully installed rails-2.3.11
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-2.3.11...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-2.3.11...

When I do this it shows me the above messages. But when I check the version with "rails -v" it displays me the following: 
"The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails"

I want to install rails version 2.3.11

I am new to rails..could anyone help me with this???

Comment: did you run `gem install` as normal user or with sudo?

Comment: No I used gem install as a normal user because sudo gem install rails -v=2.3.11 gives me the following output:
kumar@kumar-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:~$ sudo gem install rails -v=2.3.11
[sudo] password for kumar: 
sudo: gem: command not found

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is that the path to the rails binary is not in your path...
add this to your `~/.profile` file:

```
if [ -d ~/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin ] ; then
    PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin"
fi

export PATH
export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems"
```

you might need to adopt the version number of rails to fit your needs...

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this. I tried it but again the message :
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails

Comment: did you try log out and login again? if this does not help: which ruby version are you using? (find this out with `ruby -v`) and can you post the output of `ls  ~/.gem/ruby/`? and how did you install rubygems?